# What does $R[[x]]/P$ look like, for $P\lhd R[[x]]$ prime with $P\cap R = 0$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let's say, for concreteness, that $R = k[[t_1, \dots, t_m]]$. Suppose $P$ is a prime of $R[[x]]$, satisfying $P\neq 0$ and $P\cap R = 0$, and write $\mathrm{Frac}(R) = F$ and $\mathrm{Frac}(R[[x]]/P) = E$. What's the structure of $E/F$?

I had initially suspected that $E/F$ was algebraic. My proof went as follows.

1. Let $S = R\setminus \{0\}$; then we can localise $R[[x]]$ to get $S^{-1}R[[x]]$. We've assumed $P\cap S = \varnothing$, so extending $P$ gives us a prime ideal $S^{-1}P$, and it satisfies $S^{-1}P\cap R[[x]] = P$, by standard localisation properties.
2. We can further complete $(x)$-adically to get $F[[x]]$. Extending $S^{-1}P$ gives us a nonzero ideal $Q$, and it satisfies $Q\cap S^{-1}R[[x]] = S^{-1}P$ by faithful flatness.
3. All of the above shows that we have a natural inclusion $R[[x]]/P \hookrightarrow F[[x]]/Q \cong F[x]/(x^n)$ for some $n$.

Everything on the right is certainly algebraic, but that's not what worries me here: what worries me is that the image of $x+P$ is nilpotent, which implies $x\in P$. This obviously isn't the case generically. So I've messed up somewhere, but I can't put my finger on where.

What's gone wrong? And what's known about the structure of $E/F$? Or are there any similar results on the structure of $R[[x]]/P$, or is my suspicion way off?

Comment: Where does that isomorphism in step 3 comes from? We can take $P=xR[[x]]$. Then $Q=xF[[x]]$, so that $F[[x]]/Q\cong F$, which does not fit.

Comment: Why is $F\subset E$?

Comment: @HagenKnaf Sorry, that's a nasty global tendency of mine to overuse $n$ as a placeholder for an arbitrary natural number. Of course the two $n$s in this post aren't the same. I'll edit.

Comment: @Mohan I've assumed that $P\cap R = 0$. So $R\subseteq R[[x]]/P$. (Perhaps I should have written that in the main body of the post, not just the title...)

Comment: Have you looked at examples? What about the case where $P=\langle t_1\rangle$, the ideal generated by one of the variables? Beyond that, I must say that I don’t understand why $F[[x]]/Q\simeq F[x]/(x^n)$ .

Comment: @Lubin The $P$ you mention doesn't satisfy the hypothesis $P\cap R = 0$. If $P$ isn't equal to $(x)$ itself, then it has to contain some power series in $x$ with nonzero constant term. In all of the examples that I'm able to calculate, $P$ contains a polynomial, and it looks like $E/F$ is then going to be either finite (if the polynomial is monic), or perhaps some kind of completion on top of that (if not). But in general this isn't going to be true.

Comment: Also, when $F$ is a field, *all* nonzero ideals of $F[[x]]$ are $(x^n)$ for some $n\geq 0$. For some reason I had the bright idea to write $F[[x]]/(x^n)$ as the equivalent $F[x]/(x^n)$. That's all that's happening in the isomorphism in step 3.

Comment: Oh, sorry, as usual I was reading carelessly. Indeed, I was misunderstanding pretty thoroughly.  I’ll look at the question again.

Comment: How do you justify step 2? Try the example, $R=k[[x_1,x_2]]$ and $P=(x_1x-x_2)$.

Comment: @Mohan Which bit of step 2 do you disagree with? Completing $S^{-1}R[[x]]$ to $F[[x]]$ has nothing to do with $P$. The extension of $S^{-1}P$ is just its $(x)$-adic completion, because $S^{-1}R[[x]]$ is noetherian - e.g. Atiyah-MacDonald 10.13. The kernel $\ker(S^{-1}P\to Q)$ is zero, because $S^{-1}R[[x]]$ is an integral domain, e.g. A-M 10.17. And the statement on faithful flatness is standard.

Comment: The completion with $x$-adic topology is faithfully flat only if $x$ is in the Jacobson radical, which in your case may not be, as my example shows. In my example, the extended ideal $Q$ is the whole ring.

Comment: @Mohan Ah - I hadn't spotted that $x$ might not be in the Jacobson radical of $S^{-1}R[[x]]$. Thanks.